# Content- type to transfer different file types

Tags: rackspace-cloud

I want to transfer multiple type of files like .jpg,.txt,.swf etc to Rackpace Files Cloud server using PHP API.

What will be my content type?

Will it be  'Content-Type: application/octet-stream' or any other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every different extension, it can be different.

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mime_type